# xcodebuild archive- Uncaught exception: object can not be nil (key: IDEArchivePathOverride)

Tags: swift, archive, xcodebuild, xcode12

I am trying to build an iOS Framework. I found this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios

Building my project in xcode 12 works without warning, but when I try to archive it via terminal it show following error:

```
Admins-Mac-mini:TestFramework cxy$ xcodebuild archive -scheme TestFramework -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' -archivePath './build/TestFramework.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: *** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: IDEArchivePathOverride)
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 (in CoreFoundation)
  3   -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:].cold.3 (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] (in CoreFoundation)
  5   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _parseOptions] (in Xcode3Core)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7   main (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)

Abort trap: 6
```

Can anyone please tell me where I can set the IDEArchivePathOverride?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution. Unfortunately it has nothing to do with the IDEArchivePathOverride.

My terminal needed full disk access. You can set this in your settings -> Security and Privacy -> Full disk access. There you have to add the terminal app.